# NumberFormatException: Invalid BigInteger

Tags: android, biginteger, numberformatexception

Here is part of my code:

```
public class Result extends Fragment{

     BigInteger sumCipher = BigInteger.ZERO;

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.result, container, false);
         return rootView;
     }

     @Override
     public void onStart() {
         super.onStart();

         new AsyncGetSumCipher().execute();
     }        

     public void setSumCipher(BigInteger sum){
         this.sumCipher = sum;
     }

     public BigInteger getSumCipher(){
         return sumCipher;
     }
}
```

The AsyncGetSumCipher class obviously contains doInBackground and onPostExecute. The latter is as follows:

```
protected void onPostExecute(StringBuilder result) {
 super.onPostExecute(result);

     BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(result.toString());

     setSumCipher(bi);
}
```

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV9iQ.png)

Can someone please help me? I've been stuck on this for weeks now :(

Comment: Could you post the stack trace?

Comment: Also post your AsyncGetSumCipher, that seems to be doing some processing on the values

Comment: Have you logged "result.toString()" value? is it bigint?

Comment: @KartikArora edited!

Comment: @MilanNz result.toString() gives us "694727847752" which is a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by doing the following:

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(result.toString().trim().replaceAll("\"",""));
```

Comment: This means that `result.toString()` returns a quoted value?

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis Yes, it returns "694727847752"

Comment: That's weird. I thought `StringBuilder` returned plain strings?

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis I'm new to Android, I really don't know

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `result.toString()` returns invalid bigInt. Please log it and see what is the value.

**This is taken from oracle documentation:**

**BigInteger**
Constructor: `public BigInteger(String val)`

Translates the decimal String representation of a BigInteger into a BigInteger. The String representation consists of an optional minus sign followed by a sequence of one or more decimal digits. The character-to-digit mapping is provided by Character.digit. **The String may not contain any extraneous characters (whitespace, for example).**

Parameters:
val - decimal String representation of BigInteger.

Throws:
`NumberFormatException` - val is not a valid representation of a BigInteger.

See Also:

```
Character.digit(char, int)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(java.lang.String)

Comment: result.toString should return a string, right? When logged, it gives us "694727847752". The BigInteger constructor does take a string as parameter. So why am I getting this error? :(

Comment: @Mag make sure that you don't have space before first number, also try to hardcode that number in constructor just to test. I would do that but unfortunately I am not near my precious machine :)

Comment: I hardcoded the number and there is no error. It is correctly logged as 694727847752.